# cant set property of undefined vuejs 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Within my `Something.vue`:

```
<template>
<p>{{ codes }}</p>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      codes: 'test'
    }
  },
  name: 'Functions',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  setup() {
  this.codes = 'does it work?';
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Why would I face this issue?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'codes' of undefined
```

Comment: You don't have an opening `<script>` tag and you're missing a closing bracket at the end of the code. Maybe a red herring?

Answer (score 2):

In `vue3`, you can defined variable like this:

```js
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  name: 'Functions',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  setup() {
    let codes = ref('does it work?');
    
    return { codes }
  }
</script>
```

And you can use `codes` in your Vue component.

Because, in `setup` methods, you can not use `this` keywords. Its execution is earlier than other life cycle function

If you want to change `codes`, you can defined a function in `setup` or `methods`, like this:

```js
setup() {
  let codes = ref("does it work?");

  function onChangeCodes() {
    codes.value = "changed!";
  }

  return { codes, onChangeCodes };
}
```

Then, you can use this function in your template:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ codes }}</div>
  <button @click="onChangeCodes">change</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

When setup is executed, the component instance has not been created yet,
In other words, You can't access 'codes' when setup() execute.
you can check the document [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-component-properties)